# axios.post works in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, axios

**Hello Everybody!**

I have a SPA made with vuejs, and also using webpack. To make http calls, i am using axios, but something really strange is happening ...

When i use the spa on CHROME everything works fine, but ANY other browser (safari, firefox, iosSafari) gives me the following error:

```
Error: Network Error
Stack trace:
createError@webpack-internal:///34:16:15
handleError@webpack-internal:///33:88:14
```

[Error shown in console (more details)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPzPr.png)

**The code that makes this call is:**

```
  const rep = localStorage.getItem('rep')
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-access-token': token
    }
  }
  axios.post('localhost:1234/statusproducao', { representante: rep }, config)
    .then((response) => {
      Loading.hide()
      this.statusPinos = response.data.statusProducao
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      Loading.hide()
      console.log(error)
    })
```

Looking at devtools --> network, i can see that the browser didn't make the post request, and the error shown before, comes from the .catch(error) from axios.post

The const rep, and token are both strings.

What am i missing ?

Comment: Is this something to do with CORS? Which port your SPA is running on?

Comment: the api runs on localhost:1234, and has cors configured properly 
i think it's somethin in the method i'm using, as i can LOGIN in the app ...

Comment: @varunvs thanks, it actually was a cors problem.

Answer (score 0):

I added the 'x-access-token' header on my cors, and in the routes, i needed this too:

'x-access-token': token

```
  server.opts(/\.*/, function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(200)
    next()
  })
```